# wrong memcpy starting from index 1

Tags: c, memcpy

I am getting wrong `memcpy` log .

i want to take `*q` (pointer on array in size `inNumberOfFrames`) .

i want to copy it each time to a new array `buffersRing[ringNum][inNumberOfFrames]` .

when in `buffersRing[ringNum][0]` i save q's size- `inNumberOfFrames` , and the rest of q is saved into  `buffersRing[ringNum][1]-buffersRing[ringNum][inNumberOfFrames]` .

i do :

```
buffersRing[ringNum][0]=inNumberFrames;
memcpy(buffersRing[ringNum]+1, q, inNumberFrames);
```

i get wrong values. whats wrong here ?

EDIT:

but doing this instead of copy -works great :

```
 for( int k=1;k<inNumberFrames+1;k++)
     buffersRing[ringNum][k]=q[k-1];
```

Comment: What type is `buffersRing` ? How about `inNumberFrames` ?

Comment: Can you show the relevant code instead of trying to phrase it?

Comment: int16_t buffersRing , and int inNumberFrames

Comment: @netcoder this is the actually code. just a copy past

Comment: you right, but see my edit . in this question i am trying to compare between 2 ways. if you know the second way i have posted is working, than you actually dont need more info. am i wrong ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the call to `memcpy()` should be:

```
memcpy(buffersRing[ringNum]+1, q, inNumberFrames * sizeof *q);
```

since you want to copy `inNumberFrames` times the number of bytes occupied by one element of `q`.

Comment: actually if i think again i am not sure its true. every time i get q i get also its size inNumFrames. so q has inNumOfFrames samples. when you copy you give the index number am i wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the source and destination of your `memcpy` call do overlap.

You should call `memmove` in such cases.

Comment: the *q i get is an audio buffer of hardware device. you think moving it is the right way ? because previous answer did not work yet